# How to interpret a neural network in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am taking a course in machine learning and just made a neural network, but I don't know how to interpret it.

The input variables are related to wine, and the output variable is representing whether it is red or white wine. From the figure I should be able to interpret how the network predicts the type of wine, but I have no idea about how to do this, so I hope that someone can help me.

How do I interpret this neural network?

[image: Neural network of wine]

Comment: Neural networks are notoriously challenging to interpret. There's a lot of literature on it because it's one of those things where no solution is clearly "correct." https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=neural+network+interpretation&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C47&as_vis=1

Comment: It is a predictive model.  You don't care about the weights.  You care about generalization performance.  That plot isn't very useful except maybe as a diagnostic tool to see if you're getting degenerate weights.

Comment: Is it making it easier if I only have one neuron in the hidden layer? I have updated the post with another network,